# Array no Ionic de arquivo json

Tags: json, array, angular, ionic2

Tenho o seguinte documento JSON

```
"descritores": [{
        "descritor": "texto..",
        "resultado": [{
                "MediaTotal": "81,16"
            },

            {
                "MediaTotal": "81,16"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "descritor": "Texto 2..",
        "resultado": [{
                "MediaTotal": "87,01",
            },
            {
                "MediaTotal": "87,01",
            }
        ],
    },
```

E estou exibindo assim no ionic

```
 <ion-list>
         <ion-item *ngFor="let desc of descritores">
      <h2>{{desc.descritor}}</h2>
      <h3>Resultado{{desc.resultado.MediaTotal}}</h3>
      <p>Disponível</p>
</ion-item>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo exibir `desc.resultado.MediaTotal`, que é um array que está dentro de outro array, como faço pra exibir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode exibir o resultado dentro de um outro `for`:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let desc of descritores">
        <h2>{{desc.descritor}}</h2>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let media of desc.resultado">
            <h3>Resultado: {{media.MediaTotal}}</h3>            
        </ion-item> 
        <p>Disponível</p>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Na verdade o valor de MediaTotal vai ser diferente para cada um, os que eu coloquei aí foram apenas como exemplo. Então MediaTotal pode aparecer 1 ou N vezes. Como faço pra exibir todas elas?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @Leyssonguimarães

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. estava quebrando a cabeça para finalizar um módulo do meu app. vlw msm rapaziada